# How to make pull request using git

Tags: git, github

I'm working on project located in Github. Now I have made changes to the project and I want to do a pull request. I'm using this command : `git pull` but I get

```
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

How to get this to work?

Comment: Pull Requests are a GitHub feature; you need to use GitHub, not git.

Comment: How to do it with GitHub? I haven't understood their explaining

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull requests are specific to GitHub, to you have to go on github to do it, or install a command-line wrapper for GitHub, like [Hub](http://hub.github.com/), wich can allow yourself to make pull requests directly from command line with `git pull-request`.

Comment: In my opinion, the statement that pull requests are specific to GitHub is wrong. A pull request is when you ask someone else to pull from your published branch. GitHub allows you to automate the process but pull requests via mail or IRC are common in the Git world.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are working on a separate branch and have already committed your changes. If not, use `GIT commit` to commit your changes and then `git push` to push them to the remote branch in git hub. After this, use the instructions at https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request to create a pull request.